# How to get button's name from jsp to servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, getparameter

i have to log the parameter and button's name in my log file, i have code like this
jsp:

```
<form action="LoginCheck.jsp" name="logServlet" method="post"> 
            <br/>Username:<input type="text" name="username"/> 
            <br/>Password:<input type="password" name="password"/> 
            <br/><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="bt"/> 
        </form>
```

servlet(doGET):

```
String USERNAME, PASSWORD;            
            USERNAME = request.getParameter("username");
            PASSWORD = request.getParameter("password");
            String bt = request.getParameter("bt");
            System.out.println("button value = " + bt);
            writer.println("Username    :" + USERNAME + "<br>" + "Password  :" + PASSWORD + "<br>" + bt);
```

my result:
Username : null
Password : null
null

just wonder how to get the parameter? thanks...

Comment: In your form action, write the name of your Servlet page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the JSP you have given the method as `POST` and in servlet you have called the `doGet()` method.

So in your servlet use the `doPost()` instead of `doGet()` and you will get your values.

Comment: dnt forget to tick the answer

Comment: don't suggest else part because it's sensitive information and you don't want to show the password in URL.

Comment: Can you explain me how `doGet()` method is called in this case? It's Servlet not JSP. `LoginCheck.jsp` is mapped to Servlet in `web.xml`.

Comment: Hi, @Santino'Sonny'Corleone , I have a problem after cut and paste my code in doGet() to doPost(), it show a 404 error page after i submit my username and password. in my login page i have change my form to 
<form action=logservletPath method = post>
need your help

Comment: @Santino'Sonny'Corleone 
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>logServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>log.logServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>logServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/logServletPath</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
i have this in my web.xml

Comment: @user3736728 web.xml seems to be fine..hope u restarted your server after making changes on your web.xml..

Comment: @user3736728 just noticed in your question,your action goes to a JSP page(LoginCheck.jsp).Is that proper?or should it go to a servlet?

Comment: i changed my action to logServletPath already but the problem still there. i will try to restart my server first. By the way, thanks a lot for your helping.

Comment: @raymond_wmt no problem...after making changes to web.xml u need to restart d server always

Answer (score 0):

I wonder how could you get your values printed from your servlet page as you have specified the form action as the name of your JSP page instead of your servlet page..

So first the change the form action as the name of your servlet page which is I think `logServlet` in your case instead of  specifying the name of JSP page i.e `LoginCheck.jsp` and then make the changes as specified by **Santino** i.e. use `doPost()` in your Servlet instead of `doGet()`

Comment: just a simple question again. can i have 2 actions in one <form>?? because i create the loginCheck.jsp is for some if...else statement. 
and the logServlet is to record the parameters filled by user. TQ

Comment: No you cannot have 2 actions in one form..if you have different buttons in one form then either you can give the form action of same page and then check for button click and send to different pages correspondingly or you can send it to servlet page and then check button click over there..but 2 actions in one form not possible

Comment: In your case what you can do that is send it to single servlet page and do both the actions on that page i.e. logincheck and record parameters

Comment: @user3736728 If it helped do tick the answer